# JSP - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, path

Hope someone can help me. I'm getting this error when trying to display a JSP page:

```
18:41:22,674 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\leopardcreek\xxxx.pem 
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I know the path is correct and the file is there. What syntax is incorrect in that URL?

My Java part:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/leopardcreek/xxxx.pem");
req.setAttribute("keyUrl", myURL);
```

The JSP:

```
<%
String keyUrl = request.getAttribute("keyUrl").toString(); 
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(keyUrl); 
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read it as `URLStream`

```
String keyUrlString = request.getAttribute("keyUrl").toString();
URL keyURL   = new URL(keyUrlString);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(keyURL.openStream()));

String inputLine;
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
     //process
```

**Note**: placing this code on view template (.jsp) is totally discouraged

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem, it was using FileInputStream and was looking for die file on my computer eg. (c:/...) instead of using a URL.